# How to indicate flutter technique in a score?

Tags: notation, technique, trombone

And so the question:
I would like to indicate a certain bar in a trombone score using the flutter technique. How can I label and remove it correctly?

I mean labels like for strings *pizz* and *arco*

By flutter technique I mean this:

Comment: This is a great question, and the answer applies to multiple instruments. I've taken the liberty of generalizing the title, but of course please roll back if you feel the change is inappropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The notation shown in the video — the standard tremolo notation — is the correct way to indicate a flutter. In can (should) be supplemented with "f.t" (flutter tongue) for clarity.

As long as a note has no tremolo, it will be played normally.

For an extended passage, you can write "flutter" at the beginning and either use a dotted line (as in an 8va indication) or "end flutter" (or similar) to denote the passage.

Answer (score 1):

One of the pieces my Wind Ensemble is playing has this exact thing, simply notated with a tremolo marking and the word "Flutter" written over top.

ps. the piece is Clash